# Awk replacement for a slow while loop for processing a large data set

Tags: shell, awk, while-loop

I have a shell script which reads a mobile number from a file and compares with another file to determine which region the number belongs to. I have to check if the series is the first 4 digits or the first 5 digits of the number which gives me the operator and the region which the number belongs to.

If I am performing this task for about 500k numbers than the execution time for this script is about 2 hours on a machine with 24 cores and 64 GB of RAM which is a shame, hence I am here to find a better method to perform the same task more efficiently.

My code is -

```
 while read num
 do

 num4=$(echo $num | awk '{print substr($0,0,4)}'); #First 4 digits 
 num5=$(echo $num | awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}'); #First 5 digits

 taco=$(grep -w $num5 db.txt | wc -l); #Count if found in file db.txt
 taca=$(grep -w $num4 db.txt | wc -l); #Count if found in file db.txt

 if [ "$taco" -eq 0 ]; then

   if [ "$taca" -eq 0 ]; then 
      grep "$num4" mobile_db.txt >> operator_temp.txt  #If not found in db.txt file then check in different file
      else
      grep -w $num4 db.txt >> operator_temp.txt #Copy the content found to a file
   fi

  else

  grep -w $num5 db.txt >> operator_temp.txt #Copy the content found to a file
 fi

  done < output_num_temp.txt
```

Sample of db.txt file is-

```
7101    Idea    UttarPradesh(West)
7107    RelianceMobile  MadhyaPradesh
7108    RelianceMobile  Gujarat
7110    RelianceMobile  Rajasthan
73027   Airtel  UttarPradesh(West)
73028   Airtel  UttarPradesh(West)
73029   Airtel  UttarPradesh(West)
91210   Airtel  AndhraPradesh
91211   Airtel  AndhraPradesh
91212   Airtel  AndhraPradesh
```

This is also the sample for mobile_db.txt and this is the expected output that will be stored in the file operator_temp.txt

Comment: Add an example db.txt and output_num_temp.txt. Some expected results might be worthwhile as well.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs Have updated the question with samples

Comment: Two remarks. I expect the mobile_db.txt to contain mobile numbers. And secondly, is the db.txt sorted?

Comment: I think you better sort & split the `db.txt` to 1234db.txt 1235db.txt ... start with the first four digital of mobile number. so that every time only need process a small set of numbers

Comment: Yes that shell loop would be immensely slow (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output I'm sure you'll get help. Posting a few lines of text and telling us that is 2 input files and the output does not help as it doesn't demonstrate your requirements nor does it give us anything we could test a potential solution against.

Comment: Also [edit] your question to tell us how many lines db.txt and mobile_db.txt are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It SOUNDS like what you need is:

```
awk '
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { db[$1] = $0; next }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { mo[$1] = $0; next }
{ num5 = substr($1,1,5) }
num5 in db { print db[num5]; next }
{ num4 = substr($1,1,4) }
num4 in mo { print mo[num4]; next }
num4 in db { print db[num4] }
' db.txt mobile_db.txt output_num_temp.txt > operator_temp.txt
```

but without clearer requirements and more info on your input files and concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question it's just a guess.

As long as your 2 db files aren't absolutely massive the above should run in a few seconds instead of hours. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219 for a discussion of some of the many reasons why you should not use a shell loop to manipulate text.

Comment: It SOUNDS like it might be 3 orders of magnitude faster ;-)

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton, Thank you for taking the time to share this terrific solution to my issue. Would you be kind enough to explain the working of this awk script. Also inputs are mobile numbers (10digits) and sample output is the what is matched from db.txt

Comment: Hi Hi @Ed Morton, if the numbers are not found in db.txt than only the script should check in mobile_db.txt else mobile_db.txt should be skipped

Comment: That IS what the script does. Try it. I think the script is clear but if you have any specific questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: @Ed Morton, currently the script prints what is matched from the db.txt, how to change that the script prints the full number that it reads from output_num_temp.txt along with operator and region that it matched from db.txt. For example output should be in the format "7108098978    RelianceMobile  Gujarat"

Comment: Post a new question and this time include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.